# "Have fun during the exhibition"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, preposition

I'd like to say:

> Have fun during the exhibition.

in German. What I tried to find was "Ausstellungsdauer" meaning "during the exhibition" but my translation doesn't make much sense as it stand:

> viel spaß, Ausstellungsdauer.

I'm not sure about the preposition, I could user "at". Also, I'd  like to use the word "Messe" for it which is more common in Germany.

What'd be a good translation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Die Ausstellungsdauer* is actually a noun rather than a prepositional phrase, which would refer to the "duration (*die Dauer*) of the exhibit(ion)". Similarly you could use the verb *dauern* ("to last/take [time]"), as in "Wie lange dauert die Ausstellung?" ("How long does the exhibit(ion) last/take?").


For what you're asking, and if you'd rather use *Messe* instead, you might try,

> "Viel Spaß auf der Messe!" (for wishing fun while AT the event)

or

> "Viel Spaß während der Messe!" (for wishing fun DURING the event).

In this case, the preposition *auf* means "at" and uses the dative case (because it's referring to the person being at a stationary location, not moving toward it, which would need the accusative). The preposition *während* means "during" and is supposed to use the genitive case regardless, though in colloquial speech it often switches to dative as well. Since we are using a feminine noun here, it is the same form either way, so no worries there.


If you choose to stick with *Ausstellung* (if it's say maybe a smaller event than a big *Messe* covering a large parade ground, for example), then you might rather change the *auf* to *in* or *bei* as in

> "Viel Spaß bei der Ausstellung!",

still using the dative case. However, with *während* it would still be the same, as in

> "Viel Spaß während der Ausstellung!"

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin. Could you elaborate what's the difference between your first and second example? I don't quite get it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to help explain further. Glad you're back, by the way. :-)

Comment: Sorry if it's too much, but I like to be thorough enough that it might even help elsewhere. :-)

Comment: Actually, I consider it a positive thing rather than negative. Thanks a again. I even don't need to ask about the difference between "Messe" and "Ausstellung".

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks for the cleanup. I can never get the highlighting right. :-)

Answer (score 7):

An exhibition, show, fair or the like are all **places** you go rather than a **time** you spend there (as it woud be a movie, a concert or a play you visit). Therefore we use the preposition *"[auf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition)"* rather than the exclusively temporal preposition *"während"* (this would be a literal translation). *"Auf"* is used here in the meaning of both, a place, and a time span of an event. Thus we say:

> Viel Vergnügen auf der Ausstellung

Note that I replaced *Spaß"* by the less casual *"Vergnügen"* as this may fit better to a an exhibition.

Comment: Good points, and I like "Vergnügen"! :)

Comment: Während der Hannover-Messe oder der Cebit bekommst Du kaum ein Zimmer, in Hannover. Und während der Moma-Ausstellung in der Nationalgalerie konnte man da Schlangen bewundern ... `Auf der Messe` finde ich klingt opportuner, als `auf der Ausstellung` - bei letzterem läge mir `während` näher.

Answer (score 1):

The most common phrase would be:

> Viel Spaß bei der Ausstellung!

The word "Messe" usually refers to a trade fair